# Error resetting root password "Token Authentication error"

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, root

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, though this issue existed before I upgraded. I am the first user on my system so my password is the default for root but when I try to `su` to root it won't accept my password. I tried resetting the password from recovery mode but I get an error saying `Token Authentication error: password not changed`. Any ideas as to what I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu does not have the root user enabled by default, and you shouldn't need to enable it. The [RootSudo Ubuntu article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) goes into this in much detail.

The short version is: use `sudo -i` to get a root shell. See the aforementioned article's [Special Notes on sudo and Shells](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells) section if you need the root shell's environment set up in a certain way.